# What is the probability of this random variable to be negative?

Tags: probability

Let $A=1+\sigma W$ where $W$ is a standard Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $\sigma=n^{1/6}$.

What is the probability that $\mathbb{P}(A<0)$?

Here is my calculation but I doubt it to be true since it contradicts to my other analysis (very complicated to explain here)..

(1) upper bound

$\mathbb{P}(A<0)\leq \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})\rightarrow 1$

(2) lower bound

$\mathbb{P}(A<0)\geq \frac{\sqrt{4+(\frac{1}{\sigma})^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})\rightarrow 1$

So from (1) and (2) we obtain that the probability $\mathbb{P}(A<0)\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Are you interested in calculating the explicit probability that $\mathbb P(1 + n^{\frac{1}{6}} W < 0)$ or only interested in the limit $\lim_n \mathbb P(1 + n^{\frac{1}{6}}W < 0)$? Anyway, I'd suggest writing it as $\mathbb P(W < -n^{-\frac{1}{6}})$.

Comment: @DominikKutek both actually. Okay, consider $\mathbb{P}(W<-n^{-1/6})$ then when n tends to infinity, $-n^{-1/6}$ tends to $0$, then $\mathbb{P}(W<-n^{-1/6})$ tends to $1/2$, which does not align with what I wrote above.. wierd...

Comment: Your lower bound seems to me as converging to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, no?

Comment: @DominikKutek Ah yes, right, should be $1/\sqrt{2 pi}$. Then with this and "tends to $1/2$", they do not conflict each other, right?